# Почему треугольник не отображается на экране?

Tags: c++, opengl

Код должен рисовать белый треугольник. Шейдеры скомпилированы правильно.

Основной код:

```
LoadShader();
UseShader();

glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
const float vertices[] =
{
    -0.5, -0.5,
    0, 0.5,
    0.5, -0.5
};
GLuint vbo;
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), &vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 2, (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
```

Программа шейдера:

```
GLuint shader;

void LoadShader()
{
    GLuint vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    const char* vsSource = R"glsl(
        #version 150
        in vec2 position;
        //uniform mat4 model;
        void main()
        {
            gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
        }
    )glsl";
    glShaderSource(vs, 1, &vsSource, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(vs);

    GLuint fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    const char* fsSource = R"glsl(
        #version 150
        void main()
        {
            gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        }
    )glsl";
    glShaderSource(fs, 1, &fsSource, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(fs);

    shader = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shader, vs);
    glAttachShader(shader, fs);
    glLinkProgram(shader);
}

void UseShader()
{
    glUseProgram(shader);
}
```

Comment: Нужен [mcve], который можно запустить.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat код разделён на несколько файлов, сложно предоставить полный код

Comment: По ссылке объясняется, как его можно сократить. Еще могу посоветовать проверить ошибки компиляции шейдеров.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/xXiuTBfS здесь три основных файла программы. Шейдеры я тестировал.

Comment: Проверить шейдеры на ошибки компиляции. Еще совет - заменить `SDL_Delay(5000)` на нормальный event loop с `SDL_PollEvent`, и перерисовывать на каждом кадре (на каких-то операционках без event loop-а то ли окно не появляется, то ли еще что-то).

Comment: Окно отображается с чёрным фоном без белого треугольник. Раньше вместо этой простой программы рисования, у меня был более сложный код, который использовал данный шейдер, и всё работало.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat я решил проблему, добавив впереди связывания VBO создание и связывание нового VAO. Я так и не понял, почему так происходило, ведь по умолчанию должно использоваться «VAO по умолчанию» с идентификатором 0.

Comment: В core profile нет VAO по умолчанию. Он только в compatibility profile.